# Swift 3 - Displaying images from mySQL database in newsfeed

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, swift3

So I'm in the middle of designing a social media application that displays posts, comprised of a picture and a description, on a newsfeed. I am able to upload posts to our database, however, I am having problems pulling the image from the database. Specifically, I am getting an error around the code

```
 let image = post["path"] as! UIImage
```

Saying:

> "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT", while the compiler says "Could not cast
>   value of type '__NSCFString' to 'UIImage'."

Here's the entirety of my code:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var activities = [AnyObject]()
var images = [UIImage]()

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 0, 0, 0)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return activities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "activity", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    let post = activities[indexPath.row]
    print(post["path"])
    let image = post["path"] as! UIImage
    let username = post["username"] as? String
    let text = post["text"] as? String

    cell.titleLbl.text = text
    cell.userLbl.text = username
    cell.activityImage.image = image //as! UIImage
    //cell.dateLbl.text = activities[indexPath.row]
    //cell.activityImage.image = images[indexPath.row]

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    }

    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    loadActivities()
}


func loadActivities() {
    let id = user!["id"] as! String
    let url = URL(string: "https://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team7/posts.php")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let body = "id=\(id)&text=&uuid="
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if error == nil {

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    // clean up
                    self.activities.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.images.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    //self.tableView.reloadData()

                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")
                        return
                    }

                    guard let posts = parseJSON["posts"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                        print("Error while parseJSONing")
                        return
                    }


                    self.activities = posts

                    for i in self.activities.indices {

                        print("printed")
                        let path = self.activities[i]["path"] as? String

                        if let actualPath = path, !actualPath.isEmpty, let url = URL(string: actualPath) {
                            if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                                if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                                    self.images.append(image)
                                    print(self.images)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        /*
                        if path != "" {
                            //let url = URL(string: path!)!
                            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
                            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                            //let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
                            self.images.append(image)

                            */


                     else {
                            let image = UIImage()
                            self.images.append(image)
                        }

                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                } catch {
                }

            } else {
            }

        })

        }.resume()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 }

 extension NSMutableData {

func appendString(_ string : String) {

    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
    append(data!)

}

}
```

If there is anything you think I should do to improve or make the code run correctly, please let me know!

Comment: Print the value of `post["path"]`. May be you are getting back the url of the image. In that case you can't load image in that way.

Comment: Yeah, I am able to print that and get the url back. How would I load the image then?

Comment: Use `SDWebImage` for asynchronous image loading. Or else write your own method to load images from URL.